# Android v5.1.1 and SD card write issues

Tags: android, android-sdcard, sd-card

I have a Sony Z5 Compact phone with a brand new, Sandisk UHS-I U3 32GB SD card.
The card used to work for a while (like 3 weeks), but now something happened to that.
Phone is not able to write onto the card at all.
I tried formatting that from the Android, from Windows, nothing works.

Symptoms:

1.) after formatting, I can create folders and copy files onto the sd card on Windows.

2.) after formatting, I can create folders on the card on android.

3.) if I copy *anything*, really, anything from Windows to Android (to the card), the card will deny the next file write operations.

4.) seems like if it gets readonly, but mount shows sdcard1 as rw.

5.) after this, putting the card to Windows, it works okay (without formatting)

Question:
I want to format the SD card, and put back in the phone, and put some music onto that. (without having it corrupted).

Thank you.

Ps.: I hope this is some right forum for this.

Comment: "I hope this is some right forum for this" -- nope. Try https://android.stackexchange.com.